# How to create an SQL query for the scenario given below?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, associative-array

I'm having an array named `$arrResult`. I've received this array from complex JOIN SQL query. For your reference I'm printing the array here:

```
Array
(
    [21e86b3ebf6a8af2a9fcf136c4f8e88a] => 1
    [e7e95de96987cc7c89c1f0183110fb38] => 3
    [42eaca88ae0079a77604d75d30846e46] => 1
    [fc55acb1edc47d2dc339562db4c13729] => 1
    [9f27643023a83addd5eed41c4aade840] => 3
    [5810758e0ee945090506e02c35222f0e] => 3
)
```

As you can see, the keys (i.e. `test_pack_id`) are different in an array but the values (i.e. `test_pack_type_id`) are getting repeated. In some situations the values could be unique.

There is a table in database named `test_packages` having field `test_pack_id`, this field is also a primary key for that table. The `test_pack_id` field contains values from above array (i.e. the keys of above array) along with other similar values which are already present. This table has another field named `test_pack_type_id` which includes the values from the above array (i.e.1,3,etc.)

Now, I want to fetch only those records from this table where `test_pack_id` is not equal to the `test_pack_id` from above array but having the same `test_pack_type_id` associated with that particular test_pack_id.

Also, the requirement is the fetched test_pack_ids should be grouped by `test_pack_type_id`.  I tried lot of tricks to get the desired result but couldn't get it. Can anyone help me to get the desired result?

The structure of table test_packages is as follows:

```
test_pack_id       varchar(32)
test_pack_name     varchar(255)
test_pack_desc     text     
test_pack_type_id  smallint(4)
```

Comment: You should post your table structure and sql statement.

Comment: @jeroen: Thanks for your suggestion. Now I've added the table structure of table test_packages.

Comment: Please add what should the output look like

Comment: @matino:The output should contain all the test_packages as per the above criteria grouped by the test_pack_type_id. In short the query for unique test_pack_type_id should be run but it should not contain the test_packages mentioned in the above array.

Comment: will it be ok if the query extracts the test_pack_ids and then grouped using a loop

Comment: @saranbanerjee: It will be perfectly ok.

Comment: @saranbanerjee: Can you please provide the code as an answer for this question?

Comment: I have provided the code as an answer I hope it will help you solve the problem.

Comment: @saranbanerjee:Thank you so much. I think it will do what I wanted to achieve. I'll check and let you know soon.

Answer (score 4):

Here I am assuming that you have already extracted the array value given in the question from database

```
$data = Array
        (
            [21e86b3ebf6a8af2a9fcf136c4f8e88a] => 1
            [e7e95de96987cc7c89c1f0183110fb38] => 3
            [42eaca88ae0079a77604d75d30846e46] => 1
            [fc55acb1edc47d2dc339562db4c13729] => 1
            [9f27643023a83addd5eed41c4aade840] => 3
            [5810758e0ee945090506e02c35222f0e] => 3
        );
$sep = "";
$pack_str = "";
$pack_type_arr = array();
foreach($data as $key=>$val)
{
   $pack_str =  $sep.$pack_str;
   if(!in_array($val,$pack_type_arr))
        $pack_type_arr = $val;
   $sep = ",";
}
$pack_type_str = implode(",",$pack_type_arr);
$sql = "SELECT *
          FROM test_packages
          WHERE test_pack_id not in ($pack_str) 
          AND test_pack_type_id IN ($pack_type_str)             
          ORDER BY test_pack_type_id ASC";

//then execute the query and extract the resource in variable(say $query) 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $output[$row['test_pack_type_id']][] = $row['test_pack_id'];
}
//Thus $output gives you the key(test_pack_type_id) value(test_pack_id) association
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT test_pack_id,
                test_pack_type_id,
FROM test_packages
WHERE test_pack_id not in ('21e86b3ebf6a8af2a9fcf136c4f8e88a', 'e7e95de96987cc7c89c1f0183110fb38', ...)
GROUP BY test_pack_type_id
ORDER BY test_pack_type_id ASC;
```

hope I've understood the requirements correctly :)

Comment: :This won't work because I don't want to extract test_pack_type_id and the values of test_pack_ids are passed in static format. They should be passed dynamically.

Comment: yes, but you could prepare your SQL query with php. Something like @saran has shown in his example.